# Decoupling power supplies, how much should one worry about high frequency noise?

Tags: noise

When using a potentially noisy power supply, how much should you worry about noise above the frequency bands you are interested in?

For example, if I have an instrument amp with a bandwidth of 1kHz, should I be worried about 1MHz noise?

Put another way: is it common for 1MHz noise to downconvert into noise in my frequency band, or is 1MHz noise going to pretty much stay at 1MHz?

Comment: 1 kHz and 1 MHz is a bit extreme, but in general I worry most about high frequency noise, because an opamp's PSRR tends to decrease with frequency.

Comment: Just because an amplifier has a gain bandwidth of 1 kHz, is no reason to believe its power supply sensitivity has that bandwidth.   Noise can easily rectify or modulate and show up as DC or other frequencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stopping noise at the source is way better than preventing noise from, say, dropping a cell phone call.  Also, a 1MHz &, say, a 1.001MHz signal can mix creating an audible 1KHz signal. So do invest in stuff like a cheap ferrite bead to stop high freq noise.